# Why is vscode adding space between spread operator and variable name in Typescript and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, spread

"format on save" in vscode (v 1.60.2) with ALL extensions turned off consistently tries to add a space between the spread operator and variable in something like

```
return(...fobar);
```

Turns it into

```
return(... fubar);
```

which then fails to pass eslint rules my company forces on us.  I can find nothing in the settings that controls this.

Comment: what formatter are you using?

Comment: Assuming you get this behavior from a formatter together with the setting “format on save”. AFAIK there isn’t a formatter bundled with factory vscode. So it’s hard to believe you’ve disabled all extension and still experiencing this.

Comment: My two cent is, a) from command palette “reload vscode with all extensions disabled” just to be sure; and b) right click to open context menu and try “format document with…” and pick a formatter to narrow down which one cause the trouble.

Comment: I'm not using any formater.  All extensions disabled.

Comment: @hackape There are some built-in, see typescript.formatting.* in settings. But none talk about putting a space here.  Checked the javascript rules as well.